# What might stop my Firefox triggering breakpoints?

Tags: debugging, firefox

I have a fairly simple JS on a site that I know for a fact is running (checked with console.log) but firefox is not breaking on breakpoints. Chrome seems to work fine.

The only "weird" thing about these scripts is that they are source mapped.

What might make firefox ignore breakpoints?